# Changing the value of a list index inside a Queue of Lists

Tags: python, list, queue

I am trying to create a Queue in Python with the following code

```
data = queue.Queue(maxsize=4)
lists = [None] * 3
for i in range(4):
    data.put(lists)
```

Which initiates a Queue of 4 Lists with three None elements in each list as seen below

```
> print(data.queue)
deque([[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]])
```

Now, I want to edit the elements of the list in place to look like this:

```
deque([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
```

And I attempt to do so with this code:

```
x = 0
for lst in data.queue:
    for elem in lst:
        elem = x
        x += 1 
print(data.queue)
```

But it does not change the values of the list elements and still returns

```
deque([[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]])
```

Is there any way to modify the contents of the Lists inside of a Queue object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you put `lists` each time, you are referencing the same list. You need to do

```
data = queue.Queue(maxsize=4)
for _ in range(4):
    data.put([None] * 3)
    
data.queue
```

Next, use index to update values

```
x = 0
for lst in data.queue:
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        x += 1
        lst[i] = x
         
print(data.queue)
# deque([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly the solution i needed